# Can anyone tell me how to add the geolocator listen position to a google marker?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocator

I am trying to make a navigation marker on google map, for the user location I am using geolocator pub dev with the listen function however it returned as a Position? and since it have the posibility of null, it can't be used directly can anyone tell me how to do it ?

```
Position? listenToLocation()
  {
    Position? userposition;
    final LocationSettings _locationSettings = LocationSettings(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,distanceFilter: 100);
    userStreamlocation = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: _locationSettings).listen(
    (userposition) {
        print(userposition == null ? 'Unknown' : '${userposition.latitude.toString()}, ${userposition.longitude.toString()}');
        setState(){
          streamResult=userposition;
        }
    });
    return userposition;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this after finding out that the marker didn't got updated because it is in a different state than the main widget, I fix it trough the use of the statebuilder widget, here's the code snip

```
StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setMapState) {
          setMapState(
            () {},
          );

          void _whenMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
            //debugPrint('>>>>>>>>> onMapCreated');
            mapController = controller;
            _Navmarkers.clear();
            _navPolylines.clear();
            var direction =
                await LocationService().getDirectionNoWP(userOrigin, userGoal);
            _setPolylines(direction['polyline_decoded']);
            setMapState(
              () {},
            );
          }

          return Column(children: [
            Expanded(
                child: GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition:
                  CameraPosition(target: _kGooglePlex, zoom: 11),
              markers: _Navmarkers,
              polylines: _navPolylines,
              onMapCreated: _whenMapCreated,
            )),
            Row(
              children: [
                ButtonBar(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Position? userposition;

                          const LocationSettings _locationSettings =
                              LocationSettings(
                            accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
                            distanceFilter: 100,
                          );
                          userStreamlocation = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
                                  locationSettings: _locationSettings)
                              .listen((userposition) {
                            _Navmarkers.clear();
                            _Navmarkers.add(Marker(
                                markerId: MarkerId('User'),
                                position: LatLng(userposition.latitude,
                                    userposition.longitude),
                                icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                                    BitmapDescriptor.hueRose)));
                            setMapState(() {                            
                            });                            
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.navigation)),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setMapState(
                            () {                             
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh)),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          dispose();
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.stop))
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ]);
        },
      ),
```

This way the googlemap have its own state and can be refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Use onDragEnd functionality to drag the marker and release it and make sure u make 'draggable' true in the code given below....

late List dataMarkers = widget.apiDataArray.map((value) {

```
List<double> coords = value['']
    .split(',')
    .map<double>((c) => double.parse(c))
    .toList();
return Marker(
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
    onTap: () {
      AlertDialog(
        title: Text(value['']),
      );
    },
    infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: value['RECORD_NO']),
    markerId: MarkerId(value['']),
    position: LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]),
    draggable: true,
    onDragEnd: ((newPosition) async {
      try {
        final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
        if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
          print('connected');
          setState(() {
            // coords = [newPosition.latitude,newPosition.longitude];
            print(newPosition.latitude);
            print(newPosition.longitude);
            CoolAlert.show(
                title: 'Click OK To Confirm',
                context: context,
                type: CoolAlertType.confirm,
                onConfirmBtnTap: () {
                  uploadLocation(newPosition, value);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                });
            //uploadLocation(newPosition,value);
          });
        }
      } on SocketException catch (_) {
        print('not connected');
        return await QuickAlert.show(
          context: context,
          type: QuickAlertType.error,
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Please Check Your Internet!!',
        );
      }
    }));
```

}).toList();

Comment: Does it update continuously ? Since I need it to track the user until they reach location withouth the user interacting with the app at all, onDragEnd require a trigger isn't it ?

Comment: onDragEnd is triggered on long press on the marker, and it wont get updated continuously we need to update it continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

- In order to begin drag, you need to long press the marker
- set 'draggable' as true on the marker.

  ```
  var marker = Marker(
    draggable: true,
    onDrag: ((position) {}), // will fire while drag
    onDragStart: ((position) {}), // will fire at the beginning ( only once )
    onDragEnd: ((position) { // will fire at the end of dragging ( only once )
    }),
    infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
    title: 'Hello',
    snippet: 'You are here',
    ),
  );
  ```